# Better way of extending multiple interfaces

Tags: typescript, types, interface

Good evening,

Just a quick one, I am not that great at typescript and still finding my way around generics.
Surely there is a cleaner or neater way of doing the following, what would the best practice be in this scenario?

```
export interface Fruit {
  colour: string;
  age: number;
  edible: boolean;
}

export interface A {
  Apple: Fruit[];
  Banana: Fruit[];
  Peach: Fruit[];
  Plum: Fruit[];
  Melon: Fruit[];
}

export interface B {
  diffApple: Fruit[];
  diffBanana: Fruit[];
  diffPeach: Fruit[];
  diffPlum: Fruit[];
  diffMelon: Fruit[];
}

export interface FruitIndex
  extends A, B, (etc)
```

I have this situation but for multiple interfaces and it just looks really untidy.
TIA

Comment: There are no generics involved in this question.  Also, I'm not sure what you consider "tidy" and "untidy", nor am I getting which part of this you want to do in a "cleaner" or "neater" way.  Like, you could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nr2qDN) to declare `A` and `B` without as much redundancy, but maybe that's not what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yeah no generics however I thought maybe there would be a neater way making use of generics. However what you have linked is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks! Much neater.

Comment: Okay well I can write up that as an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that "tidy", "neat", and "clean" are in the eye of the beholder.  You could refactor the definitions of `A` and `B` to be less redundant.  For `A`:

```
export type A = Record<"Apple" | "Banana" | "Peach" | "Plum" | "Melon", Fruit[]>;
```

Here we are using [the `Record<K, T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype), a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which gives the same property value type `T` for each of the keys in the union `K`.  You can verify that the type is as you expect:

```
/* type A = {
    Apple: Fruit[];
    Banana: Fruit[];
    Peach: Fruit[];
    Plum: Fruit[];
    Melon: Fruit[];
} */
```

Then for type `B`:

```
export type B = { [K in keyof A as `diff${K}`]: A[K] }
```

Here we are using [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) along with [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to prepend `"diff"` to all the keys of `A` while keeping the values the same.  Again, you can verify the type is as you expect:

```
/* type B = {
    diffApple: Fruit[];
    diffBanana: Fruit[];
    diffPeach: Fruit[];
    diffPlum: Fruit[];
    diffMelon: Fruit[];
} */
```

This code is more concise than your original versions of `A` and `B`... but I don't know if it's more "tidy".  There's something to be said for code that can be understood by non-experts.  Someone looking at `` { [K in keyof A as `diff${K}`]: A[K] } `` who doesn't know what it means would probably not describe that as "clean".

---

For your `FruitIndex`, I don't see any way of making that more concise; somewhere you will need to list out all the parent interfaces you wish to extend.  You either do it after the word `extends` here, or you make some other structure which lists it out and compute `FruitIndex` from that.  Either way you'll be typing `A` and `B` a second time somewhere.  So I would leave it as-is, at least for this example:

```
export interface FruitIndex extends A, B { }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgMSgFcF4BvAKDjmwgBsIioAuOAZximQHMBuKuJm7BWSIgFsARmn7VgAEwSS6IuJIj1gmJPwC+FCqEiw4MAJ5g8AQTgBeOACVgtKPIA8AIitgwKj3AAfOA8AIW1w-yCPAAUtbAALSODougkkjwBZYAYkDwAaAmJSAG0AXQA+fgB6ACpTC2s7OEpqam9fVUISGDLZVrCkcNYuktK+6liceOGinrGBCdTxGe7ehbgsnJXRvTgaqoNDcGh4c0s4EKayOGKAaUQkOABrYDMIdDgbTDY4AANFdDoAAkZFuul+pVYVjupTg+lq9XOl3sLVaAPQ7RU2zm4zg6IGQ0Kq3mrTxCEBkwS2LWpPRKQk1JJaPJ6E2ECQjN2+wMRhOD1QGBweBGMAAkkh5KA4KBUBKflYCpdrvogA)

Comment: Out of interest, is there a way to `map` through `K` with something akin to a `.replace` method or regex literal if for example `diff` was in the middle of the string literal? so `redDiffPlum` and in the new object type you wanted it to be 'redReturnPlum' still wit the same type fruit[]?

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5Ev2N) maybe?  If this isn't what you're looking for you might want to make a new post (after searching for existing ones) since a comment section isn't the best place for detailed Q/A with code